# What alternatives are out there to RExcel?

Tags: excel, r, rexcel

We are having problems with RExcel and I am trying to find alternatives.  Our users like to use Excel and our developers like to do stats in R.  So, we use Excel as a front end for data entry, analyze in R, and present results in Excel.

Because of the problems we are having with RExcel, however, I would really like to have a different solution.  Assuming that we cannot remove Excel or R from the equation, are there other ways of connecting them besides RExcel?  My searching on the internet has not been helpful.

[edit]

I've been asked to phrase this as a problem that SO can solve.  I need to take data input in Excel, pass it to R, and get data back.  RExcel is not allowed and the transfer needs to be transparent to the user.  How do I do this?

Comment: Give us your mysterious RExcel problems and maybe we can solve them. Otherwise this Q will get closed as not constructive... As someone said in another Q recently: "Stack Overflow is not a recommendation system"

Comment: However, there is a wiki page with ways of communicating between R and Excel [here](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips%3adata-io%3ams_windows&s=excel)

Comment: @Spacedman: when there is more than one viable answer, how is StackOverflow not a recommendation system?  Aren't answers simply recommended solutions?  Anyway, I've rephrased my question.

Comment: "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site" says the faq. Anyway, you still haven't said why RExcel isn't allowed, or what your problems are with it.

Comment: While I agree, I noted that "chatty, open-ended questions" are among the most highly rated questions, and that there are even users who specialized in asking these.

Comment: If people do extensive data entry it needs to be validated. Some sort of web app with database backing is the only solution imho.  Otherwise the data validity is suspect from the get go.  `django` or ruby-on-rails`are excellent tools for this and you can validate the user input.

Comment: There are the xlsx and XLConnect packages for reading/writing. There's excel.link, which I know nothing about. And there's always the possibility to connect to Excel via an ODBC connection, I believe.

Comment: @Spacedman: why RExcel is not allowed is not the issue.  When someone asks a question about Python do they have to give a reason that their question is not about Perl?  My question is not about RExcel, I just don't know what it is about.

Comment: You said RExcel was not allowed because you were having "problems" with it. Its not unreasonable for me to ask what those problems are, because if we can fix them then problem solved. I'd rather make sure they were unsurmountable before wasting my time trying to do something else, especially when even you admit you don't know what your question is about...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps such an alternative is writing functions for Excel  in C# with ExcelDNA and R.Net libraries.

Some info:
https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Samples/tree/master/UsingRDotNet 
[How to get ExcelDNA work with R.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279908/how-to-get-exceldna-work-with-r-net)