# How to get ExcelDNA work with R.Net

Tags: c#, .net, r, excel-dna, r.net

I am a C# and R beginner trying to run the example http://mockquant.blogspot.com/2011/07/yet-another-way-to-use-r-in-excel-for.html

```
<DnaLibrary RuntimeVersion="v4.0" Name="My First XLL" Language="CS">
<ExternalLibrary Path="R.NET.dll" />
<Reference Name="R.NET" />
<![CDATA[using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using ExcelDna.Integration;
    using RDotNet;

    namespace CSLib
    {
        public class CSLib
        {
            static REngine rengine = null;
            static CSLib()
            {
                // Set the folder in which R.dll locates.
                REngine.SetDllDirectory(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.0\bin\i386");
                rengine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet", new[] { "-q" });
            }            
            [ExcelFunction(Description = "get random numbers obey to normal distribution")]
            public static double [] MyRnorm(int number)
            {
                return (rengine.EagerEvaluate("rnorm(" + number + ")").AsNumeric().ToArray<double>());
            }
        }
    }
```

I have updated the link in the line SetDLLdirectory and I tried both 32bit and 64 bit versions of R (my cpu system is win7/64 bit)

I tried with earlier stable versions of RDotNet and googled for updates to the example code, eg. here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/exceldna/7_wr8pwuCZ0/GLKlVFjr6l8J

```
    <DnaLibrary RuntimeVersion="v4.0" Name="My First XLL" Language="CS">
<ExternalLibrary Path="RDotNet.dll" />
<ExternalLibrary Path="RDotNet.NativeLibrary.dll" />
<Reference Name="RDotNet" />
<Reference Name="RDotNet.NativeLibrary" />
<![CDATA[

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ExcelDna.Integration;
using RDotNet;

namespace CSLib
{
    public class CSLib
    {
        static REngine rengine = null;
        static CSLib()
        {
            // Set the folder in which R.dll locates.
            var oldPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
            var rPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64";
    var newPath = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", rPath, System.IO.Path.PathSeparator, oldPath);

            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", newPath);
            rengine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");
        }            
        [ExcelFunction(Description = "get random numbers obey to normal distribution")]
        public static double [] MyRnorm(int number)
        {
            return (rengine.Evaluate("rnorm(" + number + ")").AsNumeric().ToArray<double>());
        }
    }
}

]]>
</DnaLibrary>
```

But I could not make it work...

After trying the older versions of r.net I also tried the newest version with the old code and then I tried to adaptthe example code present on R.Net website to the code above, presuming that initialisation of r engine now uses the path in the registry:

```
<DnaLibrary RuntimeVersion="v4.0" Name="R.NET" Description="R.NETExcel" Language="CS">
<Reference Path="RDotNet.NativeLibrary.dll"  />
<Reference Path="RDotNet.dll"  />
<Reference Path="DynamicInterop.dll"  />

<![CDATA[
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using RDotNet;
using DynamicInterop;

namespace CSLib
{
    public class CSLib
    {




        public static double[] MyRnorm(int number)
        {
        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(); 
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance(); 
            engine.Initialize();

        return (engine.Evaluate("rnorm(" + number + ")").AsNumeric().ToArray<double>());

        engine.Dispose();   
    }

    }
}
]]>

</DnaLibrary>
```

This is also giving no results. Excel function retrns #num error.

I am certain that ExcelDNA works when I comment out the section trying to connect to R and paste some other simple function like sum two values.

I believe that my problems may be related to new developments in RdotNet making the example code above obsolete (eg. it could be new way of initialising REngine instance). I am also wondering about the possibility of or 32 bit /64 bit conflict, that is why I also tried to make it work on 32 bit, win xp, dot.net 4.0 - with no results.

What then should be the right way of connecting  ExcelDNA to the current R.NET version?

Thank you very much in advance for help.

Comment: Do you have R itself installed?

Comment: You might get #NUM from your last example if you call it with 0, or omit the parameter in your Excel formula and call it as `=MyRnorm()`. This is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These steps worked fine for me:

1. Ensure the R is installed. In my Windows "Add or Remove Programs" list I see "R for Windows 3.02.
2. Create a new "Class Library" project in Visual Studio.
3. In the NuGet package Manager Console, execute the commands:

   ```
   PM> Install-Package Excel-DNA
   PM> Install-Package R.NET.Community
   ```
4. Add the following code to the main .cs file:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Linq;
   using ExcelDna.Integration;
   using ExcelDna.Logging;
   using RDotNet;

   namespace UsingRDotNet
   {
       public class AddIn : IExcelAddIn
       {
           public void AutoOpen()
           {
               MyFunctions.InitializeRDotNet();
           }

           public void AutoClose()
           {
           }
       }

       public static class MyFunctions
       {
           static REngine _engine;
           internal static void InitializeRDotNet()
           {
               try
               {
                   REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
                   _engine = REngine.GetInstance();
                   _engine.Initialize();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   LogDisplay.WriteLine("Error initializing RDotNet: " + ex.Message);
               }
           }

           public static double[] MyRnorm(int number)
           {
               return (_engine.Evaluate("rnorm(" + number + ")").AsNumeric().ToArray<double>());
           }

           public static object TestRDotNet()
           {
               // .NET Framework array to R vector.
               NumericVector group1 = _engine.CreateNumericVector(new double[] { 30.02, 29.99, 30.11, 29.97, 30.01, 29.99 });
               _engine.SetSymbol("group1", group1);
               // Direct parsing from R script.
               NumericVector group2 = _engine.Evaluate("group2 <- c(29.89, 29.93, 29.72, 29.98, 30.02, 29.98)").AsNumeric();

               // Test difference of mean and get the P-value.
               GenericVector testResult = _engine.Evaluate("t.test(group1, group2)").AsList();
               double p = testResult["p.value"].AsNumeric().First();

               return string.Format("Group1: [{0}], Group2: [{1}], P-value = {2:0.000}",  string.Join(", ", group1), string.Join(", ", group2), p);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. F5 to run the add-in in Excel.
6. Enter the formula =TestRDotNet()`and`=MyRNorm(5)`. Numbers appear in Excel.

I've added the "UsingRDotNet" project to the [Excel-DNA Samples on GitHub](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Samples).

Comment: It now works!!! I used your code plus I reinstalled the R package.
It appears that the path is now read from windows registry. And previously I did not tick "Write R version number to registry" during installation. The solution needs this entry to work. 

Thank you for help. I will use your example as template for further adventure with R in Excel! Timidly I would like to ask if it is possible to modify the example so that the relative path could be read  to a portable R (http://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/), eg. a copy of R kept in a subfolder of the compilation.

Comment: If you figure out how to deal with the portable R installation, I'd be happy to accept a pull request which updates the sample ;-)

Comment: I am now carrying a portable R from the following site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/ (also the Portable R-Studio is offered.  
The only way that comes to my mind, at my level, is to carry with me the template reg file. 
The ideal would be to still be able to indicate in the C# program, where the path is (as an alternative to reading windows registry). And then maybe it would be possible to indicate the relative path to the program itself, a subfolder with R-portable.

Comment: In short I am dreaming ab. the alternatives available to the user: either reading from registry or reading (absolute/relative) path to R installation. But so far I am very happy it works so I can play/learn more!

Comment: I have tried that with .NET Framework 4.7 and it does not work any longer. My Excel just dies....